# How can I see the matrix in which each pixel in an image is arranged

Tags: image, assembly, matrix, binary, bmp

This might sound like a silly question, but I really wanted to know how the computer process an image in the low level (binary) way(I heard images have something called a "bitmap", and the color intensity of a pixel is decided in a 24 bit number, with each pixel being organized in a matrix, I want to see this matrix), not just manipulate the image in some image editor, or high level language, how can I view the "source code" of an image?

Comment: You can use an image editor to export as ascii pnm file then you can see the pixel values in human readable form.

Comment: Or a command line tool like `convert` from ImageMagik.  Or since you have a BMP, use a hex editor to look at the binary data in the file.

Comment: For bitmaps The "24 bit number" means that there's an 8 bit number representing how bright the red should be (0 -> 255 indicating none -> full), 8 bits for blue, and 8 for green.  By turning each of these values up or down, you can form every color the human eye can [perceive](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_rgb.asp).  So if you look at a 24bit bitmap, you are seeing description of each pixel's red/blue/green (RBG).  The first 3 bytes (after the bitmap header) describe the first pixel, then the next and so on down the image.  There's some tricks and caveats, but that's the core of it.

Comment: Does we count bits in the 24 bit bitmap from left to right? (the second bit is the one to the right of the first?)

Comment: @DavidWohlferd 24 bits is not enough range to see every color, which is why you can still see banding on some images.  (Put two solid Red, Green, or Blue rectangles next to each other where one rectangle has that one intensity one higher than the other.)

Comment: Depending on the image format, it can be RGB, BGR, there might be a filler or alpha value on either end.  It could even be 30 bits, 32 bits, 16, 15, 8, 4, 2, or 1.  The color values might be absolute colors or they might be indexes into a color table.  Some image formats use compression.